# Optimize MySQL batch of different operation

Tags: mysql, optimization, spring-jdbc

#### Background

I am working on a [data sync tool](https://github.com/zzt93/syncer/) which listens change from DB, manipulates those change and sends them to another target DB.

When I was doing performance testing on MySQL, I met some problems.

#### Problems

Now I am using the Spring `JdbcTemplate#batchUpdate` to send a batch of data change to MySQL.

```java
String[] sqlStatement = new String[]{"insert ...;", "update ...;", "delete ...;"};
jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sqlStatement)
```

This kind of batch contains different kinds of operations(`insert`, `update`, `delete`) to different tables. So the `rewriteBatchedStatements=true` option is not so useful (I added this option though, not see any boost).

Now the average insert speed is about 1300/s (Elasticsearch, though, can reach 10000 and more. The following is some test result).

```sh
    time: 20190407-022652
    src=800000
    dst=9302
    time: 20190407-022654
    src=800000
    dst=12070
    time: 20190407-022656
    src=800000
    dst=14863
    time: 20190407-022658
    src=800000
    dst=17536
```

So any suggestions to optimize this kind of batch?

#### Possible Solution

- `autocommit=0;` & `commit;`?: make a whole batch in same transaction may help, but may bring some side-effect, so we are very careful about this option.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of MySQL?  If 5.7, then this may be the solution: [*Query Rewrite*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/queryrewrite).  See also the [*5.7 manual*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rewriter-query-rewrite-plugin.html).

Comment: As far as I can see from your ref, it is only about `query rewrite`, and a data sync tool sync `insert/update/delete` but no query. So, it seems not suitable?